# How can I set a static page (high_voltage) as root in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, static-pages, high-voltage

I used gem high_voltage to get static pages and it worked, but now I want to define one of them as root.
What should I write in Routes.rb since I don't have a controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the root route to a High Voltage page like this:

```
# config/initializers/high_voltage.rb

HighVoltage.configure do |config|
  config.home_page = 'home'
end
```

Which will render the page from `app/views/pages/home.html.erb` when the '/' route of the site is accessed.

Note: High Voltage also creates a search engine friendly 301 redirect. Any attempt to access the path '/home' will be redirected to '/'.

Source: https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage#specifying-a-root-path

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll remember to always read the docs completely.
Also had to reinitialize the server to see the changes...